# Xcode 7.3 Can’t install App to iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I just updated to Xcode 7.3 and my iPhone to 9.3. I changed the deployment target to 9.3 in General tab about the project in Xcode. However, on attempting to test the app on my iPhone, it fails with `Unable to install "app”`. The details are in attached image. This dialog shows up after the install to my iphone is completed.

I have delete all my dev profiles from member centre in the hope that this will go away after Xcode generates new one, but this dint work.

Apparently, the app installs and runs just fine when testing to a simulator. It only fails on a real device. Is there some change in the certs thats causeing this? How do i go around this? Just the other day I was 
able to test successfully with my iPhone from Xcode 7.2. Is it a bug with Xcode 7.3 or iOS 9.3 or both?

After reading the instruction in the comments, things look good.See image. How do i fix this?

[image: Details about the account]

[image: Error after installing to my iPhone]

Comment: go to xcode presference and accounts to see if there are any invalid issues with your dev account. Also check your keychain for any expired certificates.

Comment: seems you have a point. I have updated my question, please check if you can help.

Comment: I've had the same issue in the past when code signing for enterprise or ad hoc, instead of for development. If you don't use your development provisioning profile when debugging, it won't build onto your phone through xcode.

Answer (score 2):

This is how i fixed the problem. I opened KeyChain Access app, deleted all certificates related to this project and then navigated to member site and generated new Development certificates and profiles for the project.Now its working fine.

Comment: if you look carefully see at the error message it precisely tells you to do the same (:

Comment: yea, although the error seemed to suggest the existing certificates were expired or revoked yet the Keychain Access app showed them as valid certificates not expired.

Comment: Hello, can you explain more precisely? If I also have to more specific, I didn't understand how did you open the member site, I mean what is it?

Comment: Member site? Your Apple developer account, you need to login, navigate to certificates and provisional profiles sections and regenerate new certs and provisional profiles. You will need to download these to your Mac and click on them to install. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well, and tried everything. Regenerating all my certificates. Clearing my certificates on the keychain. Regenerating my provisioning profiles and nothing worked.

**I then simply did Product > Clean and then deleted derived data and it worked!**

Xcode must be keeping some cache of the certificates id's or something.